# Load extra fonts with lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I am preparing a document, which facilitates package `fontspec` to define the main- and the sans-font.  In that document, I'd like to compare that main font with Computer Modern or—to be precise—it successor Latin Modern.

I was convinced, that writing

```
\newfontfamily\lmfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

would enable the complete family with all its 70+ font files.  But that is not correct.

For example, when I say

```
{\lmfont\scshape{}abcd} {\scshape{}abcd}
```

I get this:

[image: Comparison of Small Capitals]

On the left side the Latin modern font, but without the small caps :-(, on the right hand side, the default ("mainfont") font of the document as it should look like.

For my comparison, I'd like to present a great selection/combination of fonts in this family, i.e. the roman, sans and mono fonts added with shapes and faces like -italic, -italic-bold, -slanted, -slanted-bold, -bold, -smallcaps.

Unfortunately, my solution only loads the `LMRoman10-Regular` and `LMSans10-Regular` fonts, but not `LMRomanCaps10-Regular`.    Thats why `\lmfont\scshape` (or `\lmfont\ttfamily`) didn't work.

So, is there a possibility, to define the `\newfamily` that it contains the complete Latin Modern fonts?

Any solution, which enables me, to have a simple macro to compare the two font families side by side would be fine.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % and other definitions
\newfontfamily\lmfont{Latin Modern Roman} % this is not complete!!

%% New command to compare.  
%% #1 defines the family/shape/series
\newcommand{\compare}[1]{%
  {#1%
    ABCD \dots{} XYZ, abcd \dots{} xyz\\
    \lmfont{}ABCD \dots{} XYZ, abcd \dots{} xyz\par
  }
}

\begin{document}
\compare{\upshape}
\compare{\itshape}
\compare{\itshape\bfseries}
\compare{\scshape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that and it really can't.

There exists no font naming convention and various fonts do very different things. Some fonts have a `smcp` feature, others don't and one has to specify the font to use for small caps.

Latin Modern Roman is in a very different situation: there are about 70 font files and it's out of the scope of `fontspec` to analyze them in order to do all necessary assignments.

However, for the particular case, `.fd` files are available, so you can use them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\newfontfamily\lmodern{Latin Modern Roman}[
  NFSSFamily=lmr
]

\begin{document}

Abc\textsc{Abc}

\lmodern

Abc\textsc{Abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As an addendum to egreg’s excellent answer: for a custom font that stores small caps in a separate file, for example named `SomeFont-RegularSC.otf` and `SomeFont-BoldSC.otf`, you would load them with

```
\newfontfamily\somefont{SomeFont}[
   UprightFont = *-Regular ,
   SmallCapsFont = *-RegularSC ,
   BoldFont = *-Bold ,
   BoldFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-BoldSC },
   % Etc.
   Extension = .otf ]
```

You can also put this command in a file named `SomeFont.fontspec` so that you can write `\newfontfamily\somefont{SomeFont}` in your documents.  This avoids leaving dependencies on one particular version of the font in all your documents.

Comment: Thank you, that was very interesting and helpful!